# Onclick event to do something

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm curently making one chrome extension which works perfect and i would like some help in one thought.

I have set my extension to work only in my website, by the manifest file.

Now i want the users when they push a button in my website with class

```
layerConfirm
```

The extension should open a new tab with a link that i want.

```
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName('layerConfirm');
    element.onclick = function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "http://example.com/"
        });
    };
```

If i put this code to the file "background.js" it will work? What is your opinion?

UPDATE:Or maybe i should put the following code in the popup.js file?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('layerConfirm');
    element.onclick = function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "http://example.com/"
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: i've already tried and nothing of those two worked. @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm nope, no errors on debugger

Comment: @wOxxOm Look i only want to make one onclick listener, so whenever someone clicks a button on the webpage (example1.com) the extension should open a new tab with (example2.com) that's all im trying to do here.

Comment: I dont understand where my code is wrong... I get the elements with classname and if the element is clicked i simple open a new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the button is on a website you can't use onclick handlers in your popup script or background script because those are totally separate documents, see [the extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) documentation.

Now, since that site is yours *the obvious and the simplest solution* would be to wrap the button in a link right inside the html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><button class="layerConfirm">123</button></a>
```

Done!

Otherwise you'll have to use messaging because `chrome.tabs.create` won't work in content scripts.

- content script that is injected on yoursite.com:

  ```
  document.querySelector('.layerConfirm').addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'confirmed'});
  });
  ```
- background script:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (msg.action == 'confirmed') {
          chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://some.url"});
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return an array list of all elements which has that class , it comes with **Elements**. If there is only one element in DOM which has this class you can use it like this `document.getElementsByClassName('layerConfirm')[0]`, otherwise use id attribute

Comment: There is only one element when i try the .length but even with the [0] object is not working.

Comment: Remove document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { }) .Probably this is not needed .Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/fj1o3h6r/1/.You will see the alert box, but since I do not have that extension you may see Cannot read property 'create' of undefined error in console